# Why the difference in speed between these SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, runtime, where-clause

I'm currently trying to write a query to sift through our ERP DB and I noticed a very odd drop in speed when I removed a filter condition.

This is what the Query looked like before (it took less than a second to complete, typically returned anywhere from 10 to hundreds of records depending on the order and item)

```
SELECT TOP 1000 jobmat.job, jobmat.suffix, jobmat.item, jobmat.matl_qty, 
      jobmat.ref_type, jobmat.ref_num, spec.NoteContent, spec.NoteDesc,
      job.ord_num, jobmat.RowPointer
FROM jobmat
INNER JOIN ObjectNotes AS obj ON obj.RefRowPointer = jobmat.RowPointer
INNER JOIN SpecificNotes AS spec ON obj.SpecificNoteToken = spec.SpecificNoteToken
INNER JOIN job ON job.job = jobmat.job AND job.suffix = jobmat.suffix
WHERE ord_num LIKE '%3766%' AND ref_type = 'P' AND 
(spec.NoteDesc LIKE '%description%' OR spec.NoteContent LIKE '%COMPANY%DWG%1162402%')
```

And this is what I changed the WHERE Statement too:

```
WHERE ord_num LIKE '%3766%' AND ref_type = 'P' AND 
spec.NoteContent LIKE '%COMPANY%DWG%1162402%'
```

Running it after having made this modifcation bumped my runtime up to like 9 seconds (returns normally 1-3 records). Is there an obvious reason that I'm missing? I would have thought that the same should have been roughly the same. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have run both versions of this query many times to test, and the runtimes are fairly consistant; <1 second for version 1, ~9 seconds for version 2.

Comment: Did you ran this query multiple times? Because performance can also depend on other things that happen on a machine.

Comment: what is the DBMS you are using,also can you paste execution plan for both the versions

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've run both versions several times and runtimes are consistant for each.

Comment: @TheGameiswar it's Microsoft SQL Server, and sorry but I do not have permissions to get at the execution plan. My primary role is not a programmer, rather I'm self taught so my knowledge is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query has to find 1000 matching rows before it returns the result set.  It is doing this by creating a result set based on the `JOIN`s and then filtering based on the `WHERE` clause.

The condition:

```
(spec.NoteDesc LIKE '%description%' OR spec.NoteContent LIKE '%COMPANY%DWG%1162402%')
```

matches more rows than:

```
(spec.NoteContent LIKE '%COMPANY%DWG%1162402%')
```

Hence, the second version has to go through and process more rows to get 1,000 matches.

That is why the second version is slower.

If you want the second version to seem faster, you can add an `ORDER BY` clause.  This requires reading all the data in both cases.  Because the `ORDER BY` then takes additional time related to the number of matching rows, you'll probably see that the second is slightly faster than the first.  One caveat:  both will then take at least 9 seconds.

EDIT:

I like the above explanation, but if all the rows are processed in both cases, then it might not be correct.  Here is another explanation, but it is more speculative.

It depends on `NoteContent` being very long, so the `LIKE` has a noticeable effect on query performance.  The second version might be "optimized" by pushing the filtering clauses to the node in the processing that reads the data.  This is something that SQL Server regularly does.  That means that the `LIKE` is being processed on *all* the data in the second case.

Because of the `OR` condition, the first example cannot push the filtering down to that level.  Then, the condition on `NoteDescription` is short-circuited in multiple ways:

- The join conditions.
- The other `WHERE` conditions.
- The first `LIKE` condition.

Because of all this filtering, the second condition is run on many fewer rows, and the code runs faster.  Usually filtering before joining is a good idea, but there are definitely exceptions to this rule.

Comment: Just a note, neither of these queries ever returned more than the cap of 1000, does this matter for your explanation? Oh, also the first version only took 1 second.

Comment: @padleyj . . . Yes that does affect this explanation.  In that case, it might simply be that you see results sooner with the first query, because it gets the data faster.

Comment: I thought about the short-circuit scenario too so one of the times I replaced the <spec.NoteDesc LIKE '%description%'> with <'0' = '1'> and wierdly enough that still bumped up the run time to 9 seconds. The more I fiddled with it though, the more I'm sure you're right, that it has to do with NoteContent.